# Nested functions not working, why?

Tags: python, python-3.3, nested-function

Here is my function which is supposed to apply another function to every element within a given iterable.

```
def transform(iterable,f):
        all=(i for i in iterable)
        return (e.f() for e in all)

for i in transform('abCdeFg','upper'):
      print(i,end='')
```

What it should do is capitalizing all the letters, but instead I get an error. What am I doing wrong? I'm using Python 3.3.

Comment: When you say "I get an error", you have to tell us what the error is. Otherwise we're just left to guess or attempt to figure it out on our own.

Comment: Don't use `all` as a variable name. You will overwrite the built-in [all](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#all)

Answer (score 4):

`e.f` is literally `e.f`. It has no relation to your `f` variable. To get an attribute by name, you use `getattr`:

```
def transform(iterable,f):
        all=(i for i in iterable)
        return (getattr(e, f)() for e in all)

for i in transform('abCdeFg','upper'):
      print(i,end='')
```

Also, you may find the builtin `map` function useful:

```
def function(l):
    return l.upper()

for i in map(function, 'abCdeFg'):
    print(i, end='')
```

Answer (score 1):

You made 2 errors:

- To call a function f on argument e, you do f(e), not e.f()
- To give a function as a parameter, gives its name, not a string with its name

So a corrected version would be:

```
   def transform(iterable, f):
     return (f(i) for i in iterable)

   for i in transform('abCdeFg', str.upper):
     print(i, end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is on this line:

```
return (e.f() for e in all)
```

The problem is that the str variable `e` doesn't have a method `f()`. You should instead:

```
def transform(iterable,f):
        all=(i for i in iterable)
        return (f(e) for e in all)

for i in transform('abCdeFg',str.upper):
      print(i,end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this just as you have written it, you need to do this:

```
def transform(s,f):
    return getattr(type(s), f)(s)


for i in transform('abCdeFg','upper'):
      print(i,end='')
```

Prints:

```
ABCDEFG
```

As others have said, this is more direct:

```
print('abCdeFg'.upper())
```

You should also not use Python built-ins as names. (i.e., Avoid calling a genex `all` because you will overwrite the built-in function [all](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#all).)

With getattr you can also return a default of the type does not have the given method:

```
>>> def transform(s,f):
...     return getattr(type(s), f, lambda s: 'no bueno')(s)
>>> transform(1,'upper')
'no bueno'
```

Or use try / except:

```
>>> def transform(s,f):
...     try:
...         return getattr(type(s), f)(s)
...     except AttributeError as e:
...         return e
... 
>>> transform(1,'upper')
AttributeError("type object 'int' has no attribute 'upper'",)
```

You can also use join with map:

```
>>> ''.join(map(lambda c: str.upper(c), 'abCdeFg'))
'ABCDEFG'
```

Or join with a comprehension:

```
>>> ''.join(c.upper() for c in 'abCdeFg')
'ABCDEFG'
```